# Subtract background from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, background-subtraction

I am trying to to subtract the background from a picture of an object to leave only the foreground object. I have found the RGB values of the background as 218 220 219 using imshow(). How can I use the RGB values with imsubtract()?

```
y = [218 220 219];
z = imsubtract(img,y);
```

*Error using imsubtract (line 55)
X and Y must have the same size and class, or Y must be a scalar double.*

[image: PencilCase]

Comment: Your img is a `mxnx3` matrix. Where the 3 components corresponds to red blue green. Your `y` is also in those components. What you want is to subtract `img(:,:,1)-218` and so on.

Comment: @TheMinion Maybe my idea was wrong but using your suggestion only leaves me with an image without the colour [220 220 220] for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) to do that

```
z = bsxfun( @minus, img, permute( [218 220 219], [1 3 2] ) );
```

You need to pay attention to data type and range. If `img` is of type `uint8` pixel values will be in range 0..255 but it will be difficult to subtract values as you'll see results underflowing at 0: `uint8(4) - uint8(10)` is `0`...
Thus, you might want to convert `img` to `double` using `im2double` having pixel values in range 0..1. In that case you'll have to convert the "gray" vector `[2218 220 219]` to 0..1 range by dividing it by `255`.
So, a more complete solution would be

```
z = bsxfun( @minus, im2double(img), permute( [218 220 219]/255, [1 3 2] ) );
```

Comment: also you should pay attention for neg. values after the subtraction

Comment: @Jak because values of `z` are **not** in range 0..1 - `z` has negative values. Try `imagesc( abs( z ) );` or `imagesc( sum( abs( z ), 3 ) );`

Answer (score -1):

The following ended up getting me closer to the answer I was looking for, although not without your guidance!

```
img = imread('IMG_0792.jpg');
img = im2double(img);

rows = numel(img(:,1,1));
columns = numel(img(1,:,1));

for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:columns
        if ( ( img(i,j,1) > 0.75) && ( img(i,j,2) > 0.7) && ( img(i,j,3) > 0.7) )
            img(i,j,1) = 1;
            img(i,j,2) = 1;
            img(i,j,3) = 1;
        end
    end
end

imshow(img);
```

Comment: -1 for (a) using `numel` instead of [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html). (b) using [`i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410) and (c) using nested loops instead of [tag:bsxfun].